# How i can be notified that the picture is captured, Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a camera application for capstone project.

At this mode my goal is the user:

1. capture a picture (main thread)
2. send the picture to a server (background thread)
3. start preview of the camera (main thread)
4. the user can capture another picture (optional)
5. Retrieve and display results from the server

I am using this code for capturing an image and it works.

```
mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, null, new PhotoHandlerGame(getApplicationContext(), mCamera));
```

My question is: How i can be notified that the picture is captured and saved so to begin sending it to the server without blocking the main thread?

**UPDATE**: After Programmer answer I added this code inside onCreate

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_mode_action);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE");
    filter.addAction("com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE");
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Image saved - broadcast receiver");
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
```

But, it doesn't work, what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static final String ACTION_NEW_PICTURE
```

Broadcast Action: A new picture is taken by the camera, and the entry of the picture has been added to the media store. getData() is URI of the picture.

Constant Value: "android.hardware.action.NEW_PICTURE"

For more Information:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE

Comment: Is there another way to do this? Like set a File Observer?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#ACTION_NEW_PICTURE you can check this link for more informatiion

Comment: This solution that you provide, it is not for a custom camera applicationthat i use. It is listening for intents of the main camera application